# Timezone conversion failed due to winter hour change pytz

Tags: python, django, dst, pytz

in my code I am trying to convert a date with pytz timezone, but due to the change to winter hour at 3 am, my code crash. I have two questions : one, why does changing hours makes the timezone conversion crash ? Two, how to avoid this bug ?
Here is my code :

```
purchase_date = make_aware(
    datetime.strptime(
        sale.findtext('n:purchasedate', namespaces={'n': ns}),
        '%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M'
    ),
    timezone('Europe/Paris')
)
```

Error returned :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    purchase_date = make_aware(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 287, in make_aware
    return timezone.localize(value, is_dst=is_dst)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytz/tzinfo.py", line 366, in localize
    raise AmbiguousTimeError(dt)
pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: 2023-10-29 02:08:00
```

Knowing that my code was executed at 3:02 am and the change of hour happened at 3:00 am.

Thanks in advance for any response !

Comment: The local time "2023-10-29 02:08:00" has existed twice, once before the DST change, and once after it, so there is no way to know what this date and time refers to. It's probably better to use UTC rather than local times to avoid such problems.

Comment: pytz.timezone `localize` method *does* have a keyword "is_dst" which can be used in exactly such cases ([docs](https://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic)). I wonder if this is implemented somehow in django. [Addendum] - seems to be [implemented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware).